# this is the error in my code "TypeError: object of type 'pygame.Surface' has no len()" and i am getting it here "if for_count >= len(for_enemy_list)"

Tags: python, pygame

this is the error in my code

> ```
> TypeError: object of type 'pygame.Surface' has no len()
> ```

and i am getting it on this statement `if for_count >= len(for_enemy_list)`

```
       if for_enemy_x == for_enemy_distance_1:
            for_enemy_list = []
            for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 1 r.png"))
            for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 2 r.png"))
            for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 3 r.png"))
            for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 4 r.png"))
            for_count += 1
            
            print("its getting till here")
            
        if for_count >= len(for_enemy_list):
            for_count = 0
                
        for_enemy_animation = for_enemy_list[for_count]
            
        
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_background_scale, (ground_1_x, 0))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_monkey_scale, (for_monkey_x, 400))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_grass, (for_grass_x, 330))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_grass_2, (for_grass_2_x, 330))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(tree_background, (for_tree_background_x, 285))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(background_creature_scale, (for_background_creature_2_x, for_background_creature_2_y))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_background_2_scale, (ground_2_x, 0))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(player_body, (for_player_body_x, 380))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(player_leg, (300, 380))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_enemy_scale, (for_enemy_x, for_enemy_y))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_ground, (for_ground_x, for_ground_y))
        SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_ball_scale, (for_ball_x, 350))
        #SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_ball_2_scale, (0, 0))
        
    pygame.display.update()
```

this the whole code for reference ........

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500

SCREEN_DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH))
for_clock = pygame.time.Clock()    

for_button_size = 30
for_button_size_1 = 30
for_button_size_2 = 30
for_button_size_3 = 30
for_button_size_4 = 30

for_check = False
for_check_2 = False
for_check_3 = False
for_check_4 = False

player_body = pygame.image.load("player1 r body.png")
player_leg = pygame.image.load("player2 r leg.png")

ground_1_x = 0
ground_2_x = 800 

for_count = 0
for_count_2 = 0

for_num = 0

for_background_creature_2_x = 630
for_background_creature_2_y = 204
for_ground_x = 0
for_ground_y = 460
for_monkey_x = 570
for_grass_x = 535
for_grass_2_x = 31
for_tree_background_x = 291
for_enemy_x = 800
for_enemy_y = 390
for_ball_x = 1200
for_player_body_x = 281

for_player_enemy_distance = False
for_player_enemy_distance_2 = False

while True:
    for_clock.tick(30)
    
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for_mouse_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN_DISPLAY, (255, 255, 255), (mouse_x, mouse_y, 1, 1))
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    class menu():
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        
        def update(self):
            global for_button_size
            global for_check
            global for_button_size_1
            global for_button_size_2
            global for_button_size_3
            global for_button_size_4
            global for_check_2
            global player_body
            global player_leg
            global for_check_3
            global for_check_4
            global keys
            global ground_1_x
            global ground_2_x
            global for_background_creature_2_x
            global for_background_creature_2_y
            global for_ground_x
            global for_grass_x
            global for_monkey_x
            global for_ground_x
            global for_ground_y
            global for_grass_2_x
            global mouse_x
            global mouse_y
            global for_mouse_rect
            
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for_mouse_rect = pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN_DISPLAY, (255, 255, 255), (mouse_x, mouse_y, 1, 1))
            
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
            self.background = pygame.image.load("background_menu.png")
            self.background_scale = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (800, 500))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.background_scale, (0, 0))
            
            self.for_button = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", for_button_size)
            self.for_button_render = self.for_button.render("PLAY", True, (255, 255, 255),  (23, 55, 55))
            self.for_button_show = SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.for_button_render, (100, 100))
            
            self.collide = for_mouse_rect.colliderect(self.for_button_show)
            
            if self.collide:
                for_button_size = 33
            else:
                for_button_size = 30
            
            if self.collide and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for_check = True
                
            if for_check == True:
                SCREEN_DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
                self.background = pygame.image.load("background_menu.png")
                self.background_scale = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (800, 500))
                SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.background_scale, (0, 0))
                
                self.for_button_2 = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", for_button_size_1)
                self.for_button_2_render = self.for_button_2.render("LEVEL 1", True, (0, 0, 0), (23, 115, 95))
                self.for_button_2_show = SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.for_button_2_render, (100, 200))
                
                self.collide_2 = for_mouse_rect.colliderect(self.for_button_2_show)
                
                if self.collide_2:
                    for_button_size_1 = 33
                else:
                    for_button_size_1 = 30    
                
                self.for_button_3 = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", for_button_size_2)
                self.for_button_3_render = self.for_button_3.render("LEVEL 2", True, (0 ,0, 0), (23, 115, 95))
                self.for_button_3_show = SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.for_button_3_render, (260, 200))
                
                self.collide_3 = for_mouse_rect.colliderect(self.for_button_3_show)
                
                if self.collide_3:
                    for_button_size_2 = 33
                else:
                    for_button_size_2 = 30
                    
                self.for_button_4 = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", for_button_size_3)
                self.for_button_4_render = self.for_button_4.render("LEVEL 3", True, (0, 0, 0), (23, 115, 95))
                self.for_button_4_show = SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.for_button_4_render, (420, 200))
                
                self.collide_4 = for_mouse_rect.colliderect(self.for_button_4_show)
                
                if self.collide_4:
                    for_button_size_3 = 33
                else:
                    for_button_size_3 = 30
                    
                if self.collide_2 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    for_check_2 = True
                        
                if self.collide_3 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    for_check_3 = True
                    
                if for_check_3 == True:
                    SCREEN_DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
                    
                if self.collide_4 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    for_check_4 = True
                    
                if for_check_4 == True:
                    SCREEN_DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
                 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        for_call = menu()
        for_call.update()
        
        if for_check_2 == True:            
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
            
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                player_body = pygame.image.load("player1 l body.png")
                player_leg = pygame.image.load("player2 l leg.png")
                ground_1_x += 10
                ground_2_x += 10
                for_background_creature_2_x += 10
                for_ground_x += 10
                for_grass_x += 10
                for_grass_2_x += 10
                for_tree_background_x += 10
                for_enemy_x += 10
                for_ball_x += 10
             
#            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
#                ground_1_x += 0
#                ground_2_x += 0
#                for_background_creature_2_x += 0
#                for_ground_x += 0
#                for_grass_x += 0
#                for_grass_2_x += 0
#                for_background_creature_2_y += 0
#                for_tree_background_x += 0        
#                for_enemy_x += 0
                
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                player_body = pygame.image.load("player1 r body.png")
                player_leg = pygame.image.load("player2 r leg.png")
                ground_1_x -= 10
                ground_2_x -= 10
                for_background_creature_2_x -= 10
                for_ground_x -= 10
                for_grass_x -= 10
                for_grass_2_x -= 10
                for_tree_background_x -= 10
                for_enemy_x -= 10
                for_ball_x -= 10
                
            for_background_creature_2_y += 2
            
            for_ball = pygame.image.load("for_ball_2.png")
            for_ball_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_ball, (20, 20))
            
            for_ball_2 = pygame.image.load("for_ball.png").convert()
            for_ball_2_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_ball_2, (50, 50))
            
        if for_check_2 == True:
            # animation1
            for_background = pygame.image.load("forest.png")
            for_background_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_background, (800, 500))
            
            tree_background = pygame.image.load("tree_background.png")
            
            for_ground = pygame.image.load("for_ground.png")
            
            background_creature = pygame.image.load("backgroundcreature.png")
            background_creature_scale = pygame.transform.scale(background_creature, (20, 20))
            
            for_background_2 = pygame.image.load("forest.png")
            for_background_2_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_background, (800, 500))
            
            enemy_1 = pygame.image.load("boar1 r.png")    
            enemy_1_scale = pygame.transform.scale(enemy_1, (80, 60))
            for_enemy_y = 370
            
            for_player_distance = for_enemy_x - 199
            for_player_distance_2 = for_enemy_x + 199
            
            for_enemy_list = pygame.image.load("boar 1 r.png")
            for_enemy_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_enemy_list, (125, 120))
            
            if for_player_body_x == for_player_distance:
                for_player_enemy_distance = True
                
            if for_player_enemy_distance == True:
                for_enemy_list = []
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar1 l.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar2 l.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar3 l.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar4 l.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar5 l.png"))
                for_count += 1
                for_enemy_y = 387    
                
                if for_count >= len(for_enemy_list):
                    for_count = 0                
                
                for_enemy_animation = for_enemy_list[for_count]
                for_enemy_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_enemy_animation, (125, 90))                
                for_enemy_y = 390       
                for_enemy_x -= 5
                
            if for_enemy_x <= for_player_body_x or for_player_body_x == for_player_distance_2:
                for_player_enemy_distance = False
                for_num = 1
                for_enemy_list = []
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar1 r.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar2 r.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar3 r.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar4 r.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar5 r.png"))
                for_count += 1
                for_enemy_y = 390
                
                if for_count >= len(for_enemy_list):
                    for_count = 0                
                
                for_enemy_x += 5
                for_enemy_animation = for_enemy_list[for_count]
                for_enemy_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_enemy_animation, (125, 90))                
                for_enemy_y = 387
            
            if for_player_enemy_distance == False and for_enemy_x >= for_player_body_x and for_num == 1: 
                for_player_enemy_distance = True
            for_grass = pygame.image.load("grass.png")
            
            for_monkey = []
            for_monkey.append(pygame.image.load("monkeys black 2.png"))
            for_monkey.append(pygame.image.load("monkeys black 2_2.png"))
            for_monkey.append(pygame.image.load("monkeys black 2_3.png"))
            for_count_2 += 0.8
            
            if for_count_2 >= len(for_monkey):
                for_count_2 = 0
            
            for_monkey_movement = for_monkey[int(for_count_2)]
            for_monkey_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_monkey_movement, (70, 70))
            
            for_monkey_x -= 10
            
            for_grass_2 = pygame.image.load("grass2.png")
            
            for_enemy_distance_1 = for_player_body_x + 4
            for_enemy_distance_2 = for_player_body_x - 45
            
            print(for_enemy_distance_1, for_enemy_x)
            
            if for_enemy_x == for_enemy_distance_1:
                for_enemy_list = []
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 1 r.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 2 r.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 3 r.png"))
                for_enemy_list.append(pygame.image.load("boar 4 r.png"))
                for_count += 1
                
                print("its getting till here")
                
            if for_count >= len(for_enemy_list):
                for_count = 0
                    
            for_enemy_animation = for_enemy_list[for_count]
                
            
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_background_scale, (ground_1_x, 0))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_monkey_scale, (for_monkey_x, 400))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_grass, (for_grass_x, 330))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_grass_2, (for_grass_2_x, 330))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(tree_background, (for_tree_background_x, 285))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(background_creature_scale, (for_background_creature_2_x, for_background_creature_2_y))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_background_2_scale, (ground_2_x, 0))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(player_body, (for_player_body_x, 380))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(player_leg, (300, 380))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_enemy_scale, (for_enemy_x, for_enemy_y))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_ground, (for_ground_x, for_ground_y))
            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_ball_scale, (for_ball_x, 350))
#            SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(for_ball_2_scale, (0, 0))
            
        pygame.display.update()

 

#if for_check_2 == True:
#SCREEN_DISPLAY.fill((255, 255, 255))
#self.creature_1 = pygame.image.load("creature.png")
#SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.creature_1, (100, 200))
#
#self.creature_2 = pygame.image.load("common monster small.png")
#self.creature_2_scale = pygame.transform.scale(self.creature_2, (60, 60))
#SCREEN_DISPLAY.blit(self.creature_2_scale, (100, 400))

           
#for_button_text_4 = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", for_button_size_change_5)
#for_button_render_4 = for_button_text_4.render("BACK", True, (0, 0, 0), (23, 115, 95))
#for_button_render_4.get_rect()
```

Comment: Are  you sure that the condition `for_enemy_x == for_enemy_distance_1` is met? Has  `for_enemy_list = []` ever been executed? Are you using `for_enemy_list` in another context? The error is not caused by the code in the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm very sure there is something like `for_enemy_list = pygame.image.load(...)` somewhere in your code.

Comment: how does that cause a problem.......?

Comment: What do you mean by "how does that cause a problem."? Read the error message. The error message is _"object of type 'pygame.Surface' has no len()"_. Hence `for_enemy_list` is a _Surface_ but not a list.

Comment: i have added the whole code i would sincerely appreciate it if you tell me how to solve it i am just a beginner and am still learning please

Comment: This statement: `for_enemy_list = pygame.image.load("boar 1 r.png")` Is loading a bitmap as a surface into your `for_enemy_list` variable. After that, the variable is a surface, not a list, and using `len(..)` on it will then give you that error. Did you mean to reuse the variable name for the surface here?

Answer (score 1):

`for_enemy_list` is supposed to be a list. Change:

<s>`for_enemy_list = pygame.image.load("boar 1 r.png")`</s>

```py
for_enemy_list = [ pygame.image.load("boar 1 r.png") ]
for_enemy_scale = pygame.transform.scale(for_enemy_list[0], (125, 120))
```